# how navigate screen of two different stacks in react native/expo

Tags: expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

### create product stack navigation  having two screen product and check out

```
const ProductStack = createStackNavigator();
function ProductStackNavigation() {    
    return (
        <ProductStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Product">
            <ProductStack.Screen
                name="Product"
                options={{
                    headerTitle: "Product",
                    headerShown: true,
                }}
                component={Product} />
            <ProductStack.Screen
                name="CheckOut"
                options={{
                    headerTitle: "CheckOut",
                    headerShown: true,
                }}
                component={CheckOut} />
        </ProductStack.Navigator>
    )
}
---
**create other favourite stack navigation  having one screen favourite**
```

---

```
const FavouriteStack = createStackNavigator();
 function FavouriteStackNavigation() {    
    return (
        <FavouriteStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Favourite">
            <FavouriteStack.Screen
                name="Favourite"
                options={{
                    headerTitle: "Favourite",
                    headerShown: true,
                }}
                component={Favourite} />          
        </FavouriteStack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

### create tab navigation conatain two stack first contain product stack and second contain favourite stack navigate from favourite screen to product screen

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    function TabNavigation() {  
        return (
            <BottomTab.Navigator
                tabBarOptions={{
                    activeTintColor: '#fafafa',              
                    labelStyle: { marginBottom: 10 }
                }}
            >
                <BottomTab.Screen
                    name="product"
                    children={() => <ProductStackNavigation />}
                    options={{
                        tabBarLabel: 'product',
                    }}
    
                />
                <BottomTab.Screen
                    name="Favourite"
                    children={() => <FavouriteStackNavigation />}
                    options={{
                        tabBarLabel: 'Favourite',
                    }}
                />
            </BottomTab.Navigator>
        )
    }
```

---

**how to navigate favourite screen to checkout screen inside favourite tab**

Answer (score 0):

You actually dont need to create "FavouriteStack". You can simply place the component Favourite in the BottomStack.Screen like this:

```
<BottomTab.Screen
   name="Favourite"
   component={Favourite}
   options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Favourite',
        }}
 />
```

And regarding navigation from Favourite to Checkout you can use useNavigation hook from "@react-natvigation/native"

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

and perform navigation using

```
navigation.navigate("ProductStack", {
       screen:"Checkout"
      })
```

Remember you need to have ProductStack as screen as well somewhere so that you can access that stack. You cant navigate to detached stacks from main navigation container. You can only switch the stacks using ternary operator.

```
isFavourite ? <FavouriteNavigator /> : <Productnavigator />
```

Comment: in above example there is only one screen suppose multiple screen in favourite then there is need of stack at that time this solution is not feasible

Comment: Its same for stack as well. You can pass Stack as screen component and it will render the first screen inside that stack. The way we jump to screen of another stack is "navigation.navigate(stackName , { screen : screenName } )"

Comment: navigation.navigate("ProductStack", { screen: 'CheckOut' })                                    The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"ProductStack","params":{"screen":"CheckOut"}} was not handled by any navigator.  generate error

Comment: Can you post your main Navigator file so that I can see the naming of stacks and screens?